# How to restrict image upload size to less than 2mb?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html `select` option for uploading images.

```html
<div class="row smallMargin">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  Attach Image
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="file" ng-model="image" accept="image/*">
</div>
</div>
```

How can I restrict the user from uploading images which are larger than 2MB?

Comment: Show me code of controller

Comment: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload check over this

Answer (score 6):

This example should give you an idea of how to do it:

**HTML**

```html
<form  class="upload-form">
    <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="2048" type="file" >
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

**JS**

```js
$(function(){
    var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
    var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
    $('.upload-form').submit(function(e){
        if(fileInput.get(0).files.length){
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
            if(fileSize>maxSize){
                alert('file size is more than ' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                return false;
            }else{
                alert('file size is correct - '+fileSize+' bytes');
            }
        }else{
            alert('Please select the file to upload');
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```